# ListView not getting updated after insertion of entries in SqliteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have read a many posts on this topic but none is helping.I have a `listview` and I have a `dialog`.The `dialog` contains three `Edittext` fields one for name,description and date.I have two `Buttons` on the dialog save and cancel. On clicking the save button , insert the data in database but `listview` doesn't get updated. 
This is the method where I specify the function of the save button :

```
save_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    selectedModel=new Model();
                    selectedModel.setTask_title(task_Title.getText().toString());
                    selectedModel.setTask_description(task_Description.getText().toString());
                    selectedModel.setTask_date(task_Date.getText().toString());
                    db.insertTask(selectedModel);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"model ="+selectedModel.getTask_title(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    //myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

I have tried using `.notifyDataSetChanged()` but it didn't work.

This is my main code where I specify all the functions :

```
public class SecondScreen extends ListActivity implements AppCompatCallback,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private Toolbar bar;
private AppCompatDelegate delegate;
List<Model> list;
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;
final Context context=this;
Model selectedModel;
AGSQLiteHelper db;

private EditText task_Title,task_Description,task_Date;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    delegate=AppCompatDelegate.create(this,this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    delegate.setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen);

    bar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbarID);
    delegate.setSupportActionBar(bar);
    ActionBar ab=delegate.getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    db=new AGSQLiteHelper(this);
    db.onUpgrade(db.getWritableDatabase(),1,2);
    db.createTask(new Model("abcde","description abcde","19/11/12"));
    db.createTask(new Model("bcdese","description bcdese","18/12/12"));
    db.createTask(new Model("mnbv","description mnbv","2/11/10"));
    db.createTask(new Model("poiuy","description poiuy","1/5/6"));
    list=db.getAllTasks();
    List<String> listTitle=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        listTitle.add(i,list.get(i).getTask_title());
    }
    myAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row,R.id.tasktitleTextID,listTitle);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    setListAdapter(myAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onSupportActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
}

@Override
public void onSupportActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public ActionMode onWindowStartingSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.add){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Add was clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Dialog");
        Button save_button=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.saveButtonID);
        Button cancel_button=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelButtonID);

        task_Title=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.titleEditTextID);
        task_Description=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.descriptionEditTextID);
        task_Date=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dateEditTextID);

        dialog.show();

        save_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                selectedModel=new Model();
                selectedModel.setTask_title(task_Title.getText().toString());
                selectedModel.setTask_description(task_Description.getText().toString());
                selectedModel.setTask_date(task_Date.getText().toString());
                db.insertTask(selectedModel);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"model ="+selectedModel.getTask_title(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
                //myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        cancel_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }


    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.done){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Done was clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Any suggestions?

Comment: post your   db.insertTask(selectedModel); method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add the new entry into the `listTitle` used by the adapter

```
db.insertTask(selectedModel);
dialog.dismiss();
listTitle.add(selectedModel.getTask_title());
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

so make your `listTitle` global to the class so that you can use it inside other functions

```
public class SecondScreen extends ListActivity...{
    private EditText task_Title;
    private List<String> listTitle;
    // declare list like this as global to class 

   ... onCreate(..){
        listTitle=new ArrayList<String>();
       }
}
```

Comment: kindly follow pavneet singh answer, notifyDataSetChanged() will work if the list is updated, you are only inserting value in DB not updating the list

Comment: @Mrinmoy i really like supportive members like yourself ,thanks

Comment: A particular row in the 'listview' has three fields one for the 'tasktitle', one for 'taskdescription', and one for 'taskdate'. If I use only 'listTitle.add(selectedModel.getTask_title());' then only the 'tasktitle' gets updated in the 'listview' and not the other two, but if I use 'listTitle.add(selectedModel.getTask_description());' and 'listTitle.add(selectedModel.getTask_date());' the values are inserted in three rows in the the listview and not in a single row.

Comment: @PritomMazumdar you are only displaying the titles of your rows in the list view as here `listTitle.add(i,list.get(i).getTask_title());`  so only you need to add `title`

Comment: @PavneetSingh Thanks friend, happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have to insert the data in a single row in the listview which has three fields. The method suggested above only inserts the data in a single field. What should I do?

Comment: @PritomMazumdar then you need to create a customize adapter , where your list will hold `Model` type of objects instead of `String` and your adapter will be able to display all the values of `Model` object , so  [follow this link](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter) and you can do lot of awesome things with custom adapter

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @PritomMazumdar i am glad that i could help , happy coding , once you are done with custom adapter then you can study recycler view( little bit length compared to listview but ) for better performance and again more awesome things like staggered view ,animation etc , happy coding